# how to force users to write on a textarea when he/she selects a choice(like a checkbox)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> 1. on Business units/Sections /customers :  </td>
    <td>
      <select>
      <option value="have a bussiness impact" id="bizyes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no bussiness impact" id="biznone"> No </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td> Describe (if Yes) </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bizyesdis" size="90" maxlength="" id="bizyesdis"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When a user selects yes from dropdown , he must describe in the indicated textbox here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGKJ3.png

Comment: You can use `javascript` or `jquery` to do this.

Comment: Your question is getting downvoted, because the question does not display any effort on reseach, and it does not show what you tried. Try looking into client side validation of forms with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isitrequired(){
  var e = document.getElementById("idoftheselect");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (strUser == "yes"){
  document.getElementById("idofthetextbox").required = true;
  }
  else{
  document.getElementById("idofthetextbox").required = false;
  }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<form action="/action_page.php">
<select id="idoftheselect" onchange="isitrequired()">
  <option value="yes">yes</option>
  <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
  Username: <input type="text" id="idofthetextbox" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Use javascript to do that.

```
var e = document.getElementById("idoftheselect");
var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if (f == "yes"){
document.getElementById("idofthetextbox").required = true;
}
else{
document.getElementById("idofthetextbox").required = false;
}
```

Dropdown:

```
<select onchange="thatjavascriptfunctionabove()">
  <option value="yes">yes</option>
  <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
```

Comment: First I wolud like to thank You. But : as you can see i have used your solution , not working :<script>
function validation()
var e = document.getElementById("bizyes");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if (strUser == "yes")
{
document.getElementById("bizyesdis").required = true;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("bizyesdis").required = false;
}
</script>

Comment: First you missing '{' after 'validation()'. Secondly any errors at the developement console in your browser?

Comment: how about this one :                                                                                                                   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function validation()
{
var e = document.getElementById("bizyes");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if (strUser == "yes")
{
document.getElementById("bizyesdis").required = true;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("bizyesdis").required = false;
}
}  I am wring now ???

Comment: still not working to me , since you used <input type="text" id="textbox" name="usrname" required> , the require attribute , in both Yes and No it asks for the user name. Remeber that my question was only for yes option.

Comment: The code above is working percetly. There is the snippet box where you can try it out. The default is yes with the required tag. If you change it to no one can submit it without any problem.

Comment: If you want it all the way around. Make no the default answer and remove required tag.

Comment: now it is working 
<form action="test.php">
<select id="bizyes" onchange="thisrequired()">
  <option value="yes">yes</option>
  <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
  Username: <input type="text" id="textbox" name="usrname">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script  type="text/javascript"> 
function thisrequired(){
  var e = document.getElementById("bizyes");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (strUser == "yes"){
  document.getElementById("textbox").required = true;
  }
  else{
  document.getElementById("textbox").required = false;
  }
 }
</script